# Python3; Bitcoin; sha256 hash; private key to wallet import format double hash not working

Tags: python-3.x, hash, sha256, private-key, bitcoin

I am trying to write my own private key to wif format code. I believe I have the base58 encoding correct, but I am not getting the same output. When I look further back into my code, I notice that my output of my double sha256 hash is not the same, which leads to a different checksum and throws everything off down the line.

Here is a bit of code where my problem lies. This part is rewritten just for this post and leaves all my other steps out that are not needed to be shown for this issue.

```
import hashlib

a = "800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D"


def double_hash(num):
    first_hash = hashlib.sha256(num.encode()).hexdigest()
    print(first_hash, "first hash")
    second_hash = hashlib.sha256(first_hash.encode()).hexdigest()
    return second_hash


def main():
    print(double_hash(a))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# ---- Output ----
# >>> e2e4146a36e9c455cf95a4f259f162c353cd419cc3fd0e69ae36d7d1b6cd2c09 first hash
# >>> fe32ab4c7a99d37256148b0dabc6390272ebe2572b943abc2580bfdacac98fbc

# ---- Expected output ----
# 8147786C4D15106333BF278D71DADAF1079EF2D2440A4DDE37D747DED5403592 first hash
# 507A5B8DFED0FC6FE8801743720CEDEC06AA5C6FCA72B07C49964492FB98A714
```

Here is my source:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how I even came about this. I was thinking that the string representation of the hex number must be converting into some other number. So I made an attempt to get it into binary format. From trial and error and I stumbled upon trying to unhexlify it and it worked.

```
import hashlib
import binascii

a = "800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D"


def double_hash(num):
    first_hash = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(num)).hexdigest()
    print(first_hash, "first hash")
    second_hash = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(first_hash)).hexdigest()
    return second_hash


def main():
    print(double_hash(a))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# ---- Output ----
# 8147786c4d15106333bf278d71dadaf1079ef2d2440a4dde37d747ded5403592 first hash
# 507a5b8dfed0fc6fe8801743720cedec06aa5c6fca72b07c49964492fb98a714

# ---- Expected output ----
# 8147786C4D15106333BF278D71DADAF1079EF2D2440A4DDE37D747DED5403592 first hash
# 507A5B8DFED0FC6FE8801743720CEDEC06AA5C6FCA72B07C49964492FB98A714
```